# how to fix when user with no-pricing role is signed in "You are not authorized to perform this action." in the landing page

Tags: spartacus-storefront

When a user with NOPRICING role (not allowed to purchase) signs in, an error shows with the following message:  "You are not authorized to perform this action. Please contact your administrator if you think this is a mistake." it happens when user is redirected to the landing page. even though MiniCart component is not provided for the user from the back-end, still the below call is made when user logs in.

The api call:

```
https://OCC_ENDPOINT/v2/SITE_CONTEXT/users/current/carts?fields=carts
```

The error message:

```
{ "errors" : [ { "message" : "Access is denied", "type" : "ForbiddenError" } ] }
```

can you please help me to stop above call on the landing page? alternatively does anyone know a reference on where initial calls on the landing page are made from so I can customize it for a NOPRICING user?

[image]

Comment: In Spartacus, when user login, user's carts will be loaded.

Comment: thanks @WeizhengGao. do you know what service initiates that? 
I'm looking for a solution to stop that call for users with specific role.

Comment: `ActiveCartService` inside `core` lib.